# LINUX: How to make 'htop' sort? F6 works, but won't let me select anything

Tags: linux, htop

I'm using **htop** in Linux, and I'm trying to set it to sort by Time+ instead of CPU%.  So I press "F6" to open the 'sort by' menu, but it won't let me select anything.  The arrow keys don't work in the 'sort by' menu, and the only options on the bottom of the screen are 'enter (sort)' and 'esc (cancel)'.

Are you not supposed to use the arrow keys in this menu?  The arrow keys work just fine in all the other setup menus, but not the 'sort by' menu.  Using pageup/pagedown sort of works; it makes the selection jump between RES and SHR, but nothing else.

Comment: That's strange, the arrow keys should work. Do you get the same behavior if you press `>` to open the menu instead of `F6`. What terminal emulator are you using? Which Linux distro and which version of `top`?

Comment: I had no idea I could use the mouse in htop, so I got it working fine with the mouse.  I tried >, same issue.  I am using Putty to SSH into my WNDR3700v2 router, running Gargoyle-OpenWRT, and I used its OPKG system to get htop.

Comment: Huh, I had no idea you could use the mouse either, cool! Your problem is probably specific to putty but could you just write that up as an answer and mark it as accepted? You get some extra [reputation](http://www.superuser.com/privileges) and it might help the next person who has this problem.

Comment: click the column twice in case you don't see sorting work, click should be done on top menu